# How to set the resource of imageview in another fragment?

Tags: android

I want to change my ImageView in the NavigationDrawer which listed in SliderFragment once I click a button listed in the AccountSettingFragment,and when I use these code

```
    final LayoutInflater factory_SL = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    final View imageEntryView_SL = factory_SL.inflate(R.layout.fragment_slider, null);
    SL_iv_avatar = (ImageView)imageEntryView_SL.findViewById(R.id.SL_profile_image);
    setFullImageFromFilePath(iv_avatar, path);
```

It doesn't work!And I tried to send a flag to NavigationDrawerFragment,however,I don't know how to set a Listener to supervise the change of the flag.

Here is my code:

```
public class AccountSettingFragment extends Fragment{
...
String path;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    final LayoutInflater factory_SL = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    final View imageEntryView_SL = factory_SL.inflate(R.layout.fragment_slider, null);
    SL_iv_avatar = (ImageView)imageEntryView_SL.findViewById(R.id.SL_profile_image);


    root.findViewById(R.id.S_UpdateAccountInfoButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                        ...

                        setFullImageFromFilePath(iv_avatar, path);

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "succeed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        ...
                    }
        ...

}
public void setFullImageFromFilePath(ImageView imageView, String path) {
    imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use EventBus library such as [GreenRobot EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) or

[Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) . It much easier to communicate between different android components with eventbus

Answer (score 0):

ImageView myImageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.img_play);

myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);

Comment: I tested it,and it doesn't work.The findViewById function return null and the app crashed.I do not know what's going on.